# Ruby api for Twilio two-way sms not working

Tags: ruby, twilio, twilio-twiml

Below is the webhook for twilio sms two-way messages. 
Whenever I reply to an sms from the phone, the below function gets called and prints from, message and messageSid, but it is unable to send the twiml response back to the phone number. I can't see any logs on twilio message logs.

```
require 'twilio-ruby'
require 'sinatra'

module Api
  module V2
    class TextableInboundController < ApplicationController
      # Respond to incoming calls with a simple text message
      def process_incoming
        from = params["From"];
        message = params["Body"];
        messageSid = params["MessageSid"];
        puts from
        puts message
        puts messageSid
        twiml = Twilio::TwiML::Response.new do |r|
          r.Message 'The Robots are coming! Head for the hills!'
        end
        twiml.text
        #Send message to user

      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Are you getting any error...Isn't that `r.message` instead of `r.Message` As per the example in Twilio documentation https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/sms/message#examples-1

Comment: How is `process_incoming` getting called as part of the Sinatra app?